# convert into unix time format in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am having the time-stamped value in nanoseconds for example, 1126732882247990. I am trying to convert into standard utc format but I am not able to convert it as most of the functions for standard utc conversion in MATLAB are limited to microsecond value.

Can someone of you help me to figure out the conversion in MATLAB.

Comment: why is it so important to use UTC format AND keep nanosecond resolution? why not separate this into two variables, one will be integer seconds (->UTC) and the other will be the nanosecond fraction that was left?

Comment: Sorry Robocop, could you please clarify your point. I am not getting it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First of all, you don't have nanoseconds as you seem to believe.**

The date 1126732882247990 can be decomposed as follows :

1126732882247990 microseconds

1126732882247 milliseconds

1126732882 seconds.

So, If you need a milliseconds precision it is quite simple:

```
  // keep only the milliseconds 
  long date = Long.parseLong("1126732882247990".substring(0,13));
```

2005-09-14 23:21:22.247

```
  // then apply whatever conversion you want
  DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS");
  df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("France"));
```

2005-09-14 09:21:22.247

If the only finality is to display it, you also can add the microseconds:

```
 String timeStamp = df.format(dateObj).concat(".").concat("1126732882247990".substring(13,16));
```

2005-09-14 09:21:22.247.990

Comment: Thanks skoll, for your reply. I recoded these values from my Android tab but I wanted to convert it into UTC from the matlab script. The value that you are getting (2005-09-14 23:21:22.247) is no-where convincing. I recorded this data in May 2014. so this output is not what I expect.

Comment: @RockStar: 1126732882247990 is in nanoseconds, 1126732882247 in microseconds, 1126732882 in miliseconds. Just use a timestamp converter you can find on the net with one of the correct imput (mili, micro, nano) and see what you get.

Comment: @Rockstar: Indeed, I've tested for you 1400000000 is 2014 in seconds not micro, so you are wrong in you title. you do not have nanosec here, you are handling micro secondes. I correct my post.

Comment: Thank @skoll, U are totally right. However, I was bit wrong in my interpretation the values that I am getting are in nanoseconds from the boot time of my android tab. These are not the timestamped values from the epoch which was undocumented in the android website.   Therefore, these values signify the number of nanoseconds that have passed from the boot time of the device. And which I think is right. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html#timestamp

Comment: ok you just had no luck that this value was potentially a timestamp date, but instead meant 13 days :) So you just have to find the right dates to test to see the format

Comment: 1400000000 is just around the corner ... Tue May 13 16:53:20 2014 +0000